# .NET 7: How to use IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider without app.UseEndpoints()

Tags: api, asp.net-core-7.0

After converting to .NET 7, I get the warning ASP0014 telling me to remove app.UseEndpoint() and register the endpoints directly on the WebApplication (app).
However, this does not work when I have code accessing the IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider service.
Running `app.Services.GetService<IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider>().ApiDescriptionGroups.Items.ToList();` now returns nothing and will also break Swagger causing it to not find any operations. But this will work fine when wrapping the registrations in UseEndpoints().

Works:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapGet("/hello", () => "Hello world!");
});
var apiDescriptions = app.Services.GetService<IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider>().ApiDescriptionGroups.Items.ToList();
```

Doesn't work:

```
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "Hello world!");
var apiDescriptions = app.Services.GetService<IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider>().ApiDescriptionGroups.Items.ToList();
```

So my questions are: What "magic" does UseEndpoints do to make this work? Can I use IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider without using UseEndpoints?

Comment: What error are you getting? How does the mapping registration break? Actual sample code would probably also be good, not just a description of the code.

Comment: I've added sample now. apiDescription will contain the endpoint in the working code. If I add Swagger, it will also display the endpoint. Without UseEndpoints, the apiDescprion will be empty and Swagger will not find any operations (No operations defined in spec!). But I see now the actual registration will still work. Changing the description to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it works correctly if it is after WebApplication is started.

```
using var _ = app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.UnsafeRegister(_ =>
{
    var api = app.Services.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider>();
}, null);

app.Run();
```